# google drive api java write file without need to create a java file first

Tags: java, google-drive-api

How to insert a text inside a google doc during the first time to insert this document, but without the need of make a text file in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from the string you want as the content, and then pass a [InputStreamContent](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/http/InputStreamContent.html) object to the `insert` method of the drive API:

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("My document");
body.setDescription("A test document");
body.setMimeType("text/plain");

final String textContent = "Hi! my first google doc!";
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(textContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent();
content.inputStream = bis;
Drive.files.insert(body, content);
```

Comment: Hi spinlok, How about adding escape characters in the textContent such as ', \, or even a new line?

Comment: You have to escape them using the usual String escaping mechanisms: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html. As an example, if you want a literal '\' , you need to use '\\' to represent within the string

Comment: I tried \n to make a new line, but it doesn't make a new line inside the document. 
I think the Drive.files.insert(body, content) need to have execute() in behind it.
And the insert doesn't work, it's only worked if I already have the file and update it with the content.

Comment: I tried it again it's worked, but I still need to insert the file without content, then update the content. I don't know why insert with content will always gave me 400 error Bad Request message.

Comment: Hi spinlok, the other escape characters are work, but newline and carriage return still didn't work.

Comment: How are you inserting newlines? `String s = "Hello\nWorld";` should work

Comment: Hi spinlok, yes, I did exactly like that, but the result I saw inside the document is just Hello World, not Hello and World on different line. I use the mime type to be 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'. thanks.