# Is there a way to write and create a text file in the google drive?

Tags: java

I have a simple server I'm writing that writes all its actions to a log file.  Write now the file is created in the current directory.  Is there a way to create a file and write to  in the google drive so I can see the actions of the server in remote locations??

My Current code

```
void NewFile(String path, String data){
     try{
        File file =new File(path);

        //if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        //true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName());
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.write("\r" );
        bufferWritter.write("\n" );
        bufferWritter.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google drive api java write file without need to create a java file first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752863/google-drive-api-java-write-file-without-need-to-create-a-java-file-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the sample on [Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java) 
Here I just pasted the specific code segment from that

```
    //Create a new authorized API client
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

    //Insert a file  
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle("My document");
    body.setDescription("A test document");
    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Check out Google Doc's API documentation.

> The Google Documents List API allows developers to create, retrieve,
>   **update**, and delete Google Docs (including but not limited to **text**
>   **documents**, spreadsheets, presentations, and drawings), files, and
>   collections. It also provides some advanced features like resource
>   archives, Optical Character Recognition, translation, and revision
>   history.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#what_can_this_api_do